# Difference between specifying a property like "UIAlertActionStyle.Default" vs ".default"?

Tags: swift

I'm a beginner at Swift and wasn't sure how to google this. I know that when you're specifying properties in Swift, you can do either:

```swift
UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default)
```

or

```swift
UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default)
```

Is there a way to refer to each way of specifying a property, and are there any differences in behavior? Is this a Swift thing or an iOS-specific thing? Links to documentation would help too. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First `UIAlertActionStyle.Default` was changed to `UIAlertAction.Style.default`

And this is specific to swift, there is no difference between writing

```
UIAlertAction (title: "OK", style: UIAlertAction.Style.default)
```

and

```
UIAlertAction (title: "OK", style: .default)
```

It's just swifty way to write the second method

Take the example of an enum:

```
enum MyEnum {
   case first, second
}
```

If we want to compare it as below:

```
let myEnum: MyEnum = .first

if myEnum == .first {
   // Action
}
```

It's more readable than:

```
let myEnum = MyEnum.first

if myEnum == MyEnum.first {
   // Action
}
```

Comment: I see, thank you for the explanation! I know this is a basic question, but how does Swift infer that `.default` means `UIAlertActionStyle.default`? Is it because `UIAlertAction`'s `style` must be `UIAlertActionStyle`?

Comment: Because the parameter of the function is of type UIAlertActionStyle so swift knows that you cannot put another type

Comment: Ahh I see, thank you. The docs told me that `UIAlertAction.Style` is an enum - so I appreciate the enum example you gave. I'm accepting your answer, but one last question : in the docs it says `UIAlertAction.Style`, not `UIAlertActionStyle` (there's an extra period). Any idea why? https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uialertaction/style

Comment: It is `UIAlertAction.Style`. this means that the enum is declared in the `UIAlertAction` class.
Before the enum was outside the class so the enum was `UIAlertActionStyle`
For example:
`
class UIAlertAction {
    enum Style {
        case default, destructive
    }
}
`

Comment: Your code snippet says `UIAlertActionStyle` but I guess those were typos then? Thank you for all your help again!